# Dwarf fortress game size in text mode

Tags: dwarf-fortress, linux

I'm trying to play Dwarf fortress in the console on Linux (more exactly, on the virtual terminal).

To archive this, I set `[PRINT_MODE:TEXT]` and I could start up dwarf fortress in the terminal/virtual console.

However, it is and remains 100x25 characters large, no matter what I change in the `FULLSCREENX/Y` and `WINDOWEDX/Y` configs, despite having plenty of room right and at the bottom.

Is there any way to increase the game size (not the font)?

Thanks